# position buttons directly under each other with html or/and css

Tags: html, css

I have the following html script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
 {% load staticfiles %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'sslcert/style.css' %}" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function oeffnefenster(url){infopopup =  window.open(url, "fenster1", "width = 700, height = 600, status=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes")}
        infopopup.focus()
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function erfolgreich(url){infopopup =  window.open(url, "fenster1", "width = 700, height = 600, status=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes")}
        infopopup.focus()
 </script>
</head>


<body>
<div class = "compprologo">
  <a href = "http://www.comp-pro.de"/>
  <img src = "{% static 'sslcert/logo_comppro.png' %}"/>
 </a>
</div>
<div class = "table">
 <table border = "0">
    {% for file in files %}
   <tr>
    <td> {{ file }}</td> 
    <td width="25%" align = "right">
      <a href="http://10.0.3.186:8000/sslcert/{{ file }}" onclick="oeffnefenster(this.href);return false">
       <font color = "white">Info</font>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td width="25%" align = "right">
      <a href="http//10.0.3.186:8000/sslcert/{{ file }}/keyCrt">
       <font color = "white">Certificate</font>
      </a>
    </td>
     <td width="25%" align = "right">
      <a href="http://10.0.3.186:8000/sslcert/{{ file }}/keyDownload">
       <font color = "white">SSL-Key</font>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td width="25%" align = "right">
      <a href="http://10.0.3.186:8000/sslcert/{{ file }}/revoke" onclick="erfolgreich(this.href);return false">
       <font color = "white">Revoke</font>
      </a>
    </td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
  </table>
</div>
<div class="AddSSL">
 <form action = "adduser.html" method = "post">{% csrf_token %}
  <input type = "submit" name = "form" style = "width:8%" value = "Add SSL-Key" class = "AddSSL">
 </form>
</div>
<div class="Downloadcrl>
 <form action = "Download crl.pem" method = "post">{% csrf_token %}
  <input type = "submit" name = "form" style = "width:8%" value = "Download crl.pem" class = "Downloadcrl">
 </form>
 </div>
</body>
```

This is how my css looks like:

```
body {
        background: url("body_bg_noise.png") repeat;
        overflow-y:scroll;
}
.AddSSL {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0.8%;
}

.Downloadcrl {
        position:fixed;
        top:4%;
}

.info {
        position:fixed;
        top:5%
        width: 30%;
}



.table {

        color: white;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 80%;
        background: black;
        border: 1px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        top:50%;
}

.idundpw {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        width: 80%;
}

ul {
        list-style-type: circle;
}

.compprologo {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        text-align:center;
        width:80%;
        background:white;
        border: 1px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
}
a:link {text-decoration:none;}
```

If you used my Monitor (1280x800), that would look delicious :P But when you would use a Monitor that is a bit smaller the two buttons: *Add SSL-Key* and *Download crl.pem* would be mixed together, because I used some pretty random percentages by who just have a synergy with my monitor size. My plan is to change the html or css, so I have these both buttons laying under each other. This is how it looks like currently: [image]

Comment: You can add a min-width in pixels to the buttons, so they don't scale under a set width

Comment: But let's say I would have a look at this site from my iPhone. Wouldn't it still scale off or something ? because I want it to be like this  http://i.imgur.com/btjjdCG.png everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop your buttons in a container like this:

```
<div class="Buttons">
    <div class="AddSSL">
     <form action = "adduser.html" method = "post">{% csrf_token %}
      <input type = "submit" name = "form" value = "Add SSL-Key" class = "AddSSL">
     </form>
    </div>
    <div class="Downloadcrl">
     <form action = "Download crl.pem" method = "post">{% csrf_token %}
      <input type = "submit" name = "form" value = "Download crl.pem" class = "Downloadcrl">
     </form>
     </div>
</div>
```

And then you can set the two button's position with the .buttons class selector to fixed, and the same should be done to the top value.

```
.buttons {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0.8%;
    width: 8%;
}

.AddSSL {
    margin-bottom: 2px; /* or something like this for the gap */
    width: 100%;
}

.Downloadcrl {
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hBHzC/